# Continuous production of keys from the bucket in Riak

Tags: erlang, riak

There is a function `stream_list_keys/2` (from `riak-erlang-client`) that allows to receive all keys in some bucket.

But this function completes sending keys after sending them all.
Is it possible to continue to getting keys? That is to receive the keys as they appear in Riak?

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished with a custom [commit hook](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/advanced/commit-hooks/) to extract the desired data from the object being stored, and send that information to a listening process.  Note though that if the precommit hook throws an exception or returns anything other than a riak object, the put operation will be aborted and the object will not be stored.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. The ability to stream keys is only based on keys that already exist. What you are asking for is the ability to "subscribe" to events which the function isn't designed for.

As Joe suggested above commit hooks are probably the best way to do what you want to do in Riak. Based on the way that you asked the question I would however recommend that you use the Post-Commit hooks (http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/advanced/commit-hooks/) instead of Pre-Commit Hooks. As Joe mentioned errors in Pre-Commit hooks can cause keys to not be persisted and I don't believe that is the behavior that you are looking for.